# jquery delayed slide-out for email subscription

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a sliding email subscription box...
I want it to slide-in at the TOP and BOTTOM of the page:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) 2ms delay after page load = Slide "Out"
2) User scrolls 1/3 from the TOP of the page = Slide "In"
3) User scrolls 1/3 from the BOTTOM of the page = Slide "Out"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can't figure out the page scroll positioning (or the third step):

http://jsfiddle.net/B7pJL/1/

```
var slide = $("div[data-slide='true']");
var opening = false;
var closing = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
console.log(pos);
if (pos > 100) {
    if (!opening) {
        opening = true; closing = false;
        slide.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            'margin-left': -350
        }, 1350, function() {
            opening = false;
        });
    }

} else {
    if (!closing) {
        closing = true; opening = false;
        slide.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0,
            'margin-left': 0
        }, 500, function() {
            closing = false;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You could save in a varible the previos scroll position, and then compare which is bigger to know if he is scrolling up or down.

Comment: That's what's throwing me off a bit, my js isn't that good... can't it just be set by page position, similar to what's already there... (pos > 100)... can't it use (pos > 50) or something similar?

Comment: You have 2 types of position, the one that the browser lets you see, and the whole page. You can save the previous scroll using 2 variables, you define currentPos at the start of window.scroll and then previousPos at the end of the function. So in the middle you can compare them